# Subleading correction to the gluon propagator in large $N$ expansion

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, quantum-chromodynamics, yang-mills, large-n

I was reading Callan, Coote and Gross' [paper](https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.13.1649) on 2-dimensional QCD, where they show that the model that 't Hooft proposes in his [work](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0550321374900881) indeed produces quark confinement. In section VIII, they analyze higher order corrections in the large $N$ expansion, and they start with the gluon self-energy, depicted by the following diagram:

[image]

Here, the $S$ in the quark propagator indicates that it is dressed with all the possible gluon interactions that can be drawn as planar diagrams, i.e. we are considering the complete quark propagators at leading order in $1/N$, which solve the 't Hooft equation. Now, I understand that because of the two quark-antiquark-gluon vertices in this propagator, we get a factor of $g^2$ which, by defining the effective finite coupling to be $g^2N$, corresponds to a factor of $1/N$, and thus is subleading in the large $N$ expansion. However, in my view this graph is unequivocally planar. As far as I understand, planar diagrams are dominant in the $N\to\infty$ limit so, how is this correction subleading? Any clarification would be appreciated.